# Postgres Full-Text Search with Hyphen and Numerals

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have observed what seems to me an odd behavior of Postgres' to_tsvector function.

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'abc-xyz');
```

returns

```
'abc':2 'abc-xyz':1 'xyz':3
```

However,

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'abc-001');
```

returns

```
'-001':2 'abc':1
```

Why not something like this?

```
'abc':2 'abc-001':1 '001':3
```

And what should I do to be able to search by the numeric portion alone, without the hyphen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be circumvented with PG13's dict-int addon's `absval` option. See [the official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/dict-int.html#id-1.11.7.20.5).

But in case you're stuck with an earlier PG version, here's the generalized version of a "number or negative number" workaround in a query.

```
select regexp_replace($$'test' & '1':* & '2'$$::tsquery::text,
            '''([.\d]+''(:\*)?)', '(''\1 | ''-\1)', 'g')::tsquery;
```

This results in:

```
'test' & ( '1':* | '-1':* ) & ( '2' | '-2' )
```

It replaces lexemes that look like positive numbers with "number or negative number" kind of subqueries.
The double cast `::tsquery::text` is just there to show how you would pass a tsquery casted to text.
Note that it handles prefix matching numeric lexemes as well.

Answer (score 9):

Seems the text search parser identifies the hyphen followed by digits to be the *sign* of a *signed integer*. Debug with [`ts_debug()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-DEBUG-TABLE):

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english', 'abc-001');

   alias   |   description   | token | dictionaries | dictionary | lexemes 
-----------+-----------------+-------+--------------+------------+---------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | abc   | {simple}     | simple     | {abc}
 int       | Signed integer  | -001  | {simple}     | simple     | {-001}
```

Other text search configurations (like 'simple' instead of 'english') won't help as the parser itself is "at fault" here (debatable).

A simple way around it (other than modifying the parser, which I never tried) would to pre-process strings and replace hyphens with m-dash (`—`) or just blanks to make sure those are identified as *"Space symbols"*. (Actual signed integers lose their negative sign in the process.)

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', translate('abc-001', '-', '—'))
    @@ to_tsquery ('english', '001');  -- true now
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=553885d30be0150acb0ca3dd901673ee)*

Comment: Thanks! Calling "translate" won't work for me, since it won't work for other use cases not mentioned here, but this would:

    WHERE to_tsvector('english', field)) @@ to_tsquery ('english', '001') OR to_tsvector('english', field)) @@ to_tsquery ('english', '-001');